# Why is my select input not increasing in size?

Tags: html, css

I've added a 'Select' HTML element to my form, but can't increase the size of it. What am I doing wrong?

```css
.contact-modal-form {
  height: 55%;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.contact-modal-form input {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  padding: 5px;
}

.contact-modal-form select {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-modal">
  <div class="contact-modal-separator">
    <p> ~ Contact Me ~ </p>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-modal-title">
    <h3>Take the first steps towards building a better future.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-modal-form">
    <h5>Your Name</h5>
    <input class="contact-modal-input" type="text" name="" value="">
    <h5>Your Email</h5>
    <input class="contact-modal-input" type="text" name="" value="">
    <h5>Your Current Website</h5>
    <input class="contact-modal-input" type="text" name="" value="">
    <h5>Your Budget</h5>
    <select class="contact-modal-input" name="">
      <option value="">~ £1000</option>
      <option value="">
        < £2000</option>
          <option value="">
            < £3000</option>
              <option value="">> £3000</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-button">
    <button type="button" name="button">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've tried changing the height, padding, line-height - all sorts. But it's simply not having it. It feels like it should be straightforward but can't figure it out.

Any quick pointers? Thanks!

Comment: Select elements are hard to style as they are parts of your operating system's UI (they look different on Mac and on Windows). Same goes for radio buttons and checkboxes.
They can be styled though. Maybe this link will give you some hints in the right direction: https://jsfiddle.net/clickstormCS/3rzw0qde/31/

Comment: with your snippet I can change all the properties that`select` let change, such as `height`

Answer (score 1):

```
.contact-modal-form select {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  height: 30px !important;
}
```

height: 30px !important; may fix it. There may other height rules overriding it so !important is required.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a demo of it, see if it helps.

```css
.contact-modal-form {
  height: 55%;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.contact-modal-form input {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  padding: 5px;
}

.contact-modal-form select {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-modal">
  <div class="contact-modal-separator">
    <p> ~ Contact Me ~ </p>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-modal-title">
    <h3>Take the first steps towards building a better future.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-modal-form">
    <h5>Your Name</h5>
    <input class="contact-modal-input" type="text" name="" value="">
    <h5>Your Email</h5>
    <input class="contact-modal-input" type="text" name="" value="">
    <h5>Your Current Website</h5>
    <input class="contact-modal-input" type="text" name="" value="">
    <h5>Your Budget</h5>
    <select class="contact-modal-form" name="">
      <option value="">~ £1000</option>
      <option value="">< £2000</option>
      <option value="">< £3000</option>
      <option value="">> £3000</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-button">
    <button type="button" name="button">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like it works on that snippet, but doesn't work in my code. Guessing it's the browser.

Comment: @JonNicholson oh, ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply padding, height etc to Select element, try adding class and use the class selector and apply padding, height etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move `height: 20px` from `.contact-modal-form select` into `.contact-modal-form input`. It's a one line change.

```css
.contact-modal-form {
  height: 55%;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.contact-modal-form input {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 20px;
}

.contact-modal-form select {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-modal">
  <div class="contact-modal-separator">
    <p> ~ Contact Me ~ </p>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-modal-title">
    <h3>Take the first steps towards building a better future.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-modal-form">
    <h5>Your Name</h5>
    <input class="contact-modal-input" type="text" name="" value="">
    <h5>Your Email</h5>
    <input class="contact-modal-input" type="text" name="" value="">
    <h5>Your Current Website</h5>
    <input class="contact-modal-input" type="text" name="" value="">
    <h5>Your Budget</h5>
    <select class="contact-modal-form" name="">
      <option value="">~ £1000</option>
      <option value="">< £2000</option>
      <option value="">< £3000</option>
      <option value="">> £3000</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-button">
    <button type="button" name="button">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of working CSS to style a select box:

```
input[type=text], select {
    padding: 6px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #5c5c5c;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width:60%;
    height: 48px;
    font-size: 24;
}
```

Select boxes are one of those things that render differently from browser to browser so you may have to add some browser specific styles.

Answer (score 0):

The padding won't matter in this case. You need to set the `width` property instead.

```css
.contact-modal-form {
  height: 55%;
  width: 60%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.contact-modal-form input {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  padding: 5px;
}

.contact-modal-form select {
  background-color: #dddddd;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-modal">
  <div class="contact-modal-separator">
    <p> ~ Contact Me ~ </p>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-modal-title">
    <h3>Take the first steps towards building a better future.</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="contact-modal-form">
    <h5>Your Name</h5>
    <input class="contact-modal-input" type="text" name="name" value>
    <h5>Your Email</h5>
    <input class="contact-modal-input" type="text" name="email" value>
    <h5>Your Current Website</h5>
    <input class="contact-modal-input" type="text" name="website" value>
    <h5>Your Budget</h5>
    <select class="contact-modal-input" name="">
      <option value="">~ £1000 </option>
      <option value="< £2000"> < £2000 </option>
      <option value=""> < £3000 </option>
      <option value="">> £3000 </option>
    </select>
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="contact-button">
    <button type="button" name="button">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```